# SQL groupby multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, group-by

Tablename: EntryTable

```
ID            CharityName           Title             VoteCount
1             save the childrens     save them            1
2             save the childrens     saving childrens     3  
3             cancer research        support them        10
```

Tablename: ContestantTable

```
ID             FirstName              LastName          EntryId 
1              Neville                Vyland               1
2              Abhishek               Shukla               1
3              Raghu                  Nandan               2
```

Desired output

```
CharityName            FullName                 
save the childrens     Neville Vyland 
                       Abhishek Shukla             
cancer research        Raghu Nandan
```

I tried

```
select LOWER(ET.CharityName) AS CharityName,COUNT(CT.FirstName) AS Total_No_Of_Contestant
  from EntryTable ET
  join ContestantTable CT
  on ET.ID = CT.ID
  group by LOWER(ET.CharityName)
```

Please advice.

Comment: can you setup an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) for this.

Comment: You should not group by ET.CharityName because this way you will not be able to get the names of the person associated with it.

Comment: as far as i know, your desired output can't be achieved using just SQL. This is why Reporting comes into effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at this [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5b896/1/0).

Have a try with this query:

```
SELECT
e.CharityName,
c.FirstName,
c.LastName, 
sq.my_count
FROM
EntryTable e
INNER JOIN ContestantTable c ON e.ID = c.EntryId
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT EntryId, COUNT(*) AS my_count FROM ContestantTable GROUP BY EntryId
  ) sq ON e.ID = sq.EntryId
```

I assumed you actually wanted to join with ContestantTable's EntryId column. It made more sense to me. Either way (joining my way or yours) your sample data is faulty.

Apart from that, you didn't want repeating CharityNames. That's not the job of SQL. The database is just there to store and retrieve the data. Not to format it nicely. You want to work with the data on application layer anyways. Removing repeating data doesn't make this job easier, it makes it worse.

Answer (score 1):

Most people do not realize that T-SQL has some cool ranking functions that can be used with grouping.  Many things like reports can be done in T-SQL.

The first part of the code below creates two local temporary tables and loads them with data for testing.

The second part of the code creates the report.  I use two common table expressions (CTE).  I could have used two more local temporary tables or table variables.  It really does not matter with this toy example.

The cte_RankData has two columns RowNum and RankNum.  If RowNum = RankNum, we are on the first instance of charity.  Print out the charity name and the total number of votes.  Otherwise, print out blanks.

The name of the contestant and votes for that contestant are show on the detail lines.  This is a typical report with sub totals show at the top.

I think this matches the report output that you wanted.  I ordered the contestants by most votes descending.

[image]

Sincerely

John Miner

[www.craftydba.com](http://www.craftydba.com)

--
-- Create the tables
--

-- Remove the tables
drop table #tbl_Entry;
drop table #tbl_Contestants;

-- The entries table
Create table #tbl_Entry
(
ID int,
CharityName varchar(25),
Title varchar(25),
VoteCount int
);

-- Add data
Insert Into #tbl_Entry values
(1, 'save the childrens', 'save them', 1),
(2, 'save the childrens', 'saving childrens', 3),
(3, 'cancer research', 'support them', 10)

-- The contestants table
Create table #tbl_Contestants
(
ID int,
FirstName varchar(25),
LastName varchar(25),
EntryId int
);

-- Add data
Insert Into #tbl_Contestants values
(1, 'Neville', 'Vyland', 1),
(2, 'Abhishek', 'Shukla', 1),
(3, 'Raghu', 'Nandan', 2);

--
-- Create the report
--

;
with cte_RankData
as
(
  select 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY E.CharityName ASC, VoteCount Desc) as RowNum,
    RANK() OVER (ORDER BY E.CharityName ASC) AS RankNum,
    E.CharityName as CharityName,
    C.FirstName + ' ' + C.LastName as FullName,
    E.VoteCount
  from #tbl_Entry E inner join #tbl_Contestants C on E.ID = C.ID
),

cte_SumData
as
(
  select 
    E.CharityName,
    sum(E.VoteCount) as TotalCount
  from #tbl_Entry E
  group by E.CharityName
)

select 
    case when RowNum = RankNum then
        R.CharityName
    else
        ''
    end as rpt_CharityName,
    case when RowNum = RankNum then
        str(S.TotalCount, 5, 0)
    else
        ''
    end as rpt_TotalVotes,
    FullName as rpt_ContestantName,
    VoteCount as rpt_Votes4Contestant
from cte_RankData R join cte_SumData S 
on R.CharityName = S.CharityName